# Generic Adder from Idris to Scala?

Tags: scala, shapeless, idris

[Type Driven Development with Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) presents the following generic adder approach:

```
AdderType : (numArgs : Nat) -> Type
AdderType Z     = Int
AdderType (S k) = (next : Int) -> AdderType k

adder : (n : Nat) -> (acc : Int) -> AdderType n
adder Z acc     = acc
adder (S k) acc = \x => (adder k (x+acc))
```

Example:

```
-- expects 3 Int's to add, with a starting value of 0
*Work> :t (adder 3 0) 
adder 3 0 : Int -> Int -> Int -> Int

-- 0 (initial) + 3 + 3 + 3 == 9
*Work> (adder 3 0) 3 3 3
9 : Int
```

I'm guessing that [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) can handle the above generic `adder` function.

How can it be written in Scala with or without shapeless?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: I'll leave my original implementation below, but here's one that's a little more direct:

```
import shapeless._

trait AdderType[N <: Nat] extends DepFn1[Int]

object AdderType {
  type Aux[N <: Nat, Out0] = AdderType[N] { type Out = Out0 }
  def apply[N <: Nat](base: Int)(implicit at: AdderType[N]): at.Out = at(base)

  implicit val adderTypeZero: Aux[Nat._0, Int] = new AdderType[Nat._0] {
    type Out = Int
    def apply(x: Int): Int = x
  }

  implicit def adderTypeSucc[N <: Nat](implicit
    atN: AdderType[N]
  ): Aux[Succ[N], Int => atN.Out] = new AdderType[Succ[N]] {
    type Out = Int => atN.Out
    def apply(x: Int): Int => atN.Out = i => atN(x + i)
  }
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val at3 = AdderType[Nat._3](0)
at3: Int => (Int => (Int => Int)) = <function1>

scala> at3(3)(3)(3)
res8: Int = 9
```

Original answer below.

---

Here's an off-the-cuff Scala translation:

```
import shapeless._

trait AdderType[N <: Nat] extends DepFn1[Int] {
  protected def plus(x: Int): AdderType.Aux[N, Out]
}

object AdderType {
  type Aux[N <: Nat, Out0] = AdderType[N] { type Out = Out0 }

  def apply[N <: Nat](base: Int)(implicit at: AdderType[N]): Aux[N, at.Out] =
    at.plus(base)

  private[this] case class AdderTypeZero(acc: Int) extends AdderType[Nat._1] {
    type Out = Int
    def apply(x: Int): Int = acc + x
    protected def plus(x: Int): Aux[Nat._1, Int] = copy(acc = acc + x)
  }

  private[this] case class AdderTypeSucc[N <: Nat, Out0](
    atN: Aux[N, Out0],
    acc: Int
  ) extends AdderType[Succ[N]] {
    type Out = Aux[N, Out0]
    def apply(x: Int): Aux[N, Out0] = atN.plus(acc + x)
    protected def plus(x: Int): Aux[Succ[N], Aux[N, Out0]] = copy(acc = acc + x)
  }

  implicit val adderTypeZero: Aux[Nat._1, Int] = AdderTypeZero(0)
  implicit def adderTypeSucc[N <: Nat](implicit
    atN: AdderType[N]
  ): Aux[Succ[N], Aux[N, atN.Out]] = AdderTypeSucc(atN, 0)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val at3 = AdderType[Nat._3](0)
at3: AdderType[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]] { ...

scala> at3(3)(3)(3)
res0: Int = 9
```

It's more verbose and the representation is a little different to get the Scala syntax to work out—our "base case" is essentially an `Int => Int` instead of an `Int` because otherwise I don't see a way to avoid needing to write `apply` or `()` everywhere—but the basic ideas are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

In case you're on a long trip and don't have your *shapeless* on hands, here is how you can do this in pure Scala. It can be useful for those who are not familiar with *shapeless* and those who don't use it for some reason.

First of all, we'll need some way to iterate on types, i.e. represent natural numbers in types. You can use any nested type or just define a new one with some aliases for numbers:

```
sealed trait Nat

trait Zero extends Nat
trait Succ[N <: Nat] extends Nat

// enough for examples:
type _0 = Zero
type _1 = Succ[_0]
type _2 = Succ[_1]
type _3 = Succ[_2]
type _4 = Succ[_3]
// etc...
```

Of course, if you will often use types like `_42` and `_342923`, it would be *more* convenient to take an existing `Nat` type with some macro-magic for constructing those from values, but for our examples it's enough.

Now, the `AdderType` dependent function type is quite straight forward:

```
// first we define the type which take a Nat type argument
trait AdderType[N <: Nat] {

  type Out
  def apply(i: Int): Out
}

// then we inductively construct its values using implicits
case object AdderType {

  // base case: N = _0
  implicit def zero:
      AdderType[_0] { type Out = Int } =
  new AdderType[_0] {

    type Out = Int
    def apply(i: Int): Out = i
  }

  // induction step: N -> Succ[N]
  implicit def succ[N <: Nat, NOut](
    implicit prev: AdderType[N] { type Out = NOut }
  ):  AdderType[Succ[N]] { type Out = Int => NOut } =
  new AdderType[Succ[N]] {

    type Out = Int => NOut
    def apply(i: Int): Out = k => prev(i + k)
  }
}
```

Now, to construct an instance of `AdderType` and apply it, we write a function, which takes a `N <: Nat` as a type argument and implicitly constructs `AdderType[N]`:

```
def adder[N <: Nat](initial: Int)(
  implicit adderFunction: AdderType[N]
): adderFunction.Out = adderFunction(initial)
```

That's it:

```
scala> val add3Numbers = adder_[_3](0)
add3Numbers: Int => (Int => (Int => Int)) = <function1>

scala> add3Numbers(1)(2)(3)
res0: Int = 6
```

You can see that the pure solution is not much bigger or more complicated than the one using *shapeless* (although the latter provides us ready-to-use `Nat` and `DepFn` types).

---

A little addition: if *(in some more general case)* you don't want to use `adderFunction.Out`, which sometimes leads to problems, I also have a solution without it. In this particular case it's not any better, but I'll show it anyway.

The key point is to add another type parameter for the out type: `adder[N <: Nat, NOut]`, but then can't pass `N` as a type to `adder`, because we will need to write `NOut`, which want to be inferred (otherwise, what's the point). So we can pass an additional value argument, which will help to derive `N` type:

```
def adder[N <: Nat, NOut](n: NatVal[N])(initial: Int)(
  implicit adderFunction: AdderType[N] { type Out = NOut }
): NOut = adderFunction(initial)
```

To construct `NatVal[N]` we don't need to create an instance of each `Nat` type, we can use a little trick:

```
// constructing "values" to derive its type arg
case class NatVal[N <: Nat]()

// just a convenience function
def nat[N <: Nat]: NatVal[N] = NatVal[N]()
```

Now here is how you use it:

```
scala> val add3Numbers = adder(nat[_3])(0)
add3Numbers: this.Out = <function1>

scala> add3Numbers(1)(2)(3)
res1: this.Out = 6
```

You can see that it works, but doesn't show us the actual types. Nevertheless, this approach can work better in cases when you have several implicits that depend others' type members. I mean

```
def foo[AOut]()(implicit
  a: A { type Out = AOut},
  b: B { type In = AOut }
) ...
```

instead of

```
def foo()(implicit
  a: A,
  b: B { type In = a.Out }
) ...
```

Because you cannot reffer to `a.Out` in the same argument list.

---

You can find full code in my [repo](https://github.com/laughedelic/scala-adder) on Github.